# Whats wrong with my coding?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So on a site they have a "level" where I need to take a lot of words put them in alphabetical order and then paste it in the answer box and then hit submit and all doing this in five seconds? I am using the console to execute the code which is as follows:

```
var id = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].innerHTML;
id = id.sort();    
id = id.join(",");
document.getElementsByName("answer")[0].innerHTML = id;
```

can someone tell me why it doesnt work though? I get the

`/*
Exception: TypeError: id.sort is not a function
@Scratchpad/1:11:6
*/`

Can anyone tell me whats wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `sort()` doesn't work on string but array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because `id` is a string, not an array.  You probably want to have a line like:

```
id = id.split(" ") //whatever the separator is
```

above the `id.sort()` line.